# How to force to restart computer after installations complete

Tags: installation, package, setup-deployment

How can I set my application setup so that it forces computer to restart after installations is finished?

Thanks

Comment: Indicating what is the target system (Windows, I suppose, other systems rarely need such restart), and what installation software you use could be useful...

Comment: nsis, nullsoft, izpack, installjammer or bitrock?

Comment: Which installer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If using C# override your view `Close()` so no manual closing and perform the next when the user clicks on reboot:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-r -t 0");
```

If using some prebuilt (like install shield)  from 'Installation Designer' tab -> 'Behavior and Logic' -> 'Custom Actions and Sequences' -> 'Sequences' -> 'Installation' -> 'Execute' -> 'ScheduleReboot' set the value of 'Conditions' to "NOT REMOVE" (with out the inverted commas) if you want the reboot to happen after install and to "REMOVE" if after uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

In an MSI installer you can set [REBOOT property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371101%28VS.85%29.aspx) to **Force**. Optionally, you can also set [REBOOTPROMPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371104%28VS.85%29.aspx) to **Suppress**.